# When is a hypothesis test appropriate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, proportion, parametric

For example, when would a hypothesis test bed used?

Comment: Whatever you do in statistics depends on your aim, i.e., what you want to find out. "If I know that the proportion of people who play basketball increased from 3.1% to 4.5% over 4 years" - couldn't that be enough to know? What more would you want to know for which you'd need a hypothesis test?

Comment: Hi, why did you shorten and alter the question? I think it should be rolled back to the previous (more detailed and informative) version, unless you have a strong reason for the change.

Comment: Yeah changed for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a fair question and the answer relates to the difference between taking a population census and taking a sample. It depends of how the statistics of 3.1% and 4.5% were obtained. Do you have complete data or were the proportions estimated from a sample of your target population?

If you have complete data, i.e., if you know the total number of people who play basketball in your target population, then there is indeed no purpose in a hypothesis test. You already know the truth.

If the proportions were instead estimated by polling a random collection of people, say by telephone or by a questionaire, then a hypothesis test would be needed in order to confirm that the increase from 3.1% to 4.5% is statistically significant and likely to be representative of the whole population. The null hypothesis in this case would be that the proportion has not changed. As well as conducting a hypothesis test, it would also be useful to attach a "margin of error" to each of the proportions, as is often done for political polls.

Answer (score 0):

inferential statistical tests (ISTs) = hypothesis test

> Many commentators have argued that there is nothing inherently wrong
> with inferential statistics and that problems only arise when they are
> used inappropriately or interpreted incorrectly. The main problem with
> this counterargument is that it is difficult – perhaps even impossible
> – to find examples of published research where these two criteria have
> actually been met. The authors have repeatedly asked those defending
> the use of ISTs to provide examples of their own work where ISTs have
> been used and interpreted correctly, and have never had more than an
> evasive response.

-AGAINST INFERENTIAL STATISTICS: HOW AND WHY CURRENT STATISTICS TEACHING GETS IT WRONG by PATRICK WHITE and STEPHEN GORARD (2017), Statistics Education Research Journal, 16(1), 55-65, http://iase-web.org/Publications.php?p=SERJ.

Essentially, hypothesis testing as it is taught nowadays in statistics course in universities is meaningless, misleading and mostly unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to CV! This is a reasonable position to take, but the answer would be better if the argument in the last sentence was fleshed out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

NHST = Null Hypothesis Significance Testing

"Why NHST is seriously flawed? There are several reasons why NHST is a flawed and irrational technique for analyzing scientific results.

Statistical significance does not tell us what we want to know.
The vast majority of null hypotheses are false and scientifically irrelevant.
P-values are only indirectly related to posterior probability.
The p-value distribution is very large.
The alternative hypotheses might be even more unlikely.
It uses arbitrary cutoffs and contributes to black-and-white thinking.
It can, at best, only test statistical (not substantive) null hypotheses.
Increases type-I error rate in published papers.
Contributes substantially to publication bias.
Overestimates effect sizes in published papers.

Not only flawed in many respects, NHST is also chronically misunderstood and abused."

quoted from https://debunkingdenialism.com/2014/11/10/why-p-values-and-statistical-significance-are-worthless-in-science/